# Kusto, Performing operations based on a condition

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to write a Kusto query, where I have a bool variable and based on that variable I want to call different functions.
For example:

```
let flag = true;
let result = iff(flag == "true", function1, function2)
// function1 will return a different table and function2 will return another table.
```

The above code is not possible because the methods like `iff() and case()` can only be operated on scalar values.

So, Is there any way that I could achieve this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the common technique is using a union:

```
union (function1 | where flag), (function2 | where not(flag))
```

Here is a full example:

```
let A = datatable(col1:string)["A"];
let B = datatable(col1:string)["B"];
let funcA = view(){
        A
    };
let funcB= view(){
        B
    };
let flag = true;
union (funcA() | where flag), (funcB() | where not(flag))
```

| col1 |
| --- |
| A |

And when the flag is false:

```
let A = datatable(col1:string)["A"];
let B = datatable(col1:string)["B"];
let funcA = view(){
        A
    };
let funcB= view(){
        B
    };
let flag = false;
union (funcA() | where flag), (funcB() | where not(flag))
```

| col1 |
| --- |
| B |

Comment: I have tried this, but it is executing both the functions. But I want only one of them to get executed.

Comment: This can't be, you are probably doing something different. I added a full example, try it out, and see why your query is different.

Comment: If the set of columns returned by funcA is different than the set from funcB, then this Q&A comes in handy: [Dynamically return columns from a kusto function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67395722/986533)