# Kusto dynamic table union (append if variable flag is set)

Tags: union, azure-data-explorer, kql

is the following logic possible in Kusto:

```
let flag = True;

let view = {

Table1
if flag:
| union
Table2

};
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes it answers the question

Answer (score 1):

see: [Kusto, Performing operations based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606373/kusto-performing-operations-based-on-a-condition)

```
union (function1 | where flag), (function2 | where not(flag))
```